# How to parse this csv to an array with php

Tags: php, csv

What is the best way to parse this cross domain csv file to an array?

Example data:

```
2015-03-26 01:00;     1,428;    39,513
2015-03-26 02:00;     1,425;    39,294
2015-03-26 03:00;     1,422;    39,076
2015-03-26 04:00;     1,421;    39,004
2015-03-26 05:00;     1,416;    38,642
2015-03-26 06:00;     1,416;    38,642
2015-03-26 07:00;     1,416;    38,642
2015-03-26 08:00;     1,416;    38,642
```

I tried something like this:

```
$file = fopen("http://somedomain.com/data.csv", "r");
while (($buffer = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $fields = explode(";", $buffer);    
    print_r(fgetcsv($file));
    }    
fclose($file);
```

But it still splits the data at the comma, not semicolon. I'd be happy for any suggestions!

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/fgetcsv), you need to pass a 3rd param  of `;` to get it to split by a semi-colon.

Comment: Actually your code works fine.  add `print_r($fields)` and you will see the actual result of splitting at your specified delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), specifying ';' as the delimiter in the third argument. For example:

```
$fh = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ';'))) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-03-26 01:00
    [1] =>      1,428
    [2] =>     39,513
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-03-26 02:00
    [1] =>      1,425
    [2] =>     39,294
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-03-26 03:00
    [1] =>      1,422
    [2] =>     39,076
)
// etc.
```

Hope this helps :)